# How to create "Sub Menu" in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack Compose offers "TopAppBar" to replace "Appbar"(or Toolbar) , and use DropdownMenuItem to create a menu item. I was wondering how to create a sub menu like what we did before.

**A menu item including a sub menu**
[image: A menu item including a sub menu]

**Click it and expand the sub menu**
[image: expand the sub menu]

Comment: Use a DropdownMenu inside the DropdownMenuItem

Comment: thank you. however ,  because the main menu is expanded so this new sub menu shows in the left on the screen , which is not what i expected. can you help me?

Comment: You can retrieve the offsetx to apply to the nested DropdownMenu

Comment: @FunnySaltyFish Can you post the answer?